# Network-wide StackExchange sites really slow

Tags: bug, stack-exchange

Lately I've had problems with all stack exchange sites (which excludes chat and a51, but not entirely). The problem is that they are *so slow to load*.

for example, trying to load the [questions in Computer Science Educators](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions) or simply doing a [review on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/) can take 78 seconds to load the page, and the review often fails:

[image]

and checking with [this nice chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-load-time/fploionmjgeclbkemipmkogoaohcdbig?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) I can see that for the Computer Science Educators questions page, this is the result:

[image: oh boy]

Which shows that the DOM is taking a long time, and that everything overall takes a long time (judging by the `When` column). This **only** happens on sites in the SE network, and **only** on a specific PC.
So, what can I do?

PS, I am using chrome version 61.0.3141.8 and all the things listed in [this faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need) are enabled\unblocked\good to go.  Plus, I'm using windows 10 (and latest update)

<sub><sub>please don't hate me, if it were my way I'd use some Linux dist.</sub></sub>

[teststackoverflow](https://teststackoverflow.com/) shows this:
[image]

Comment: please provide more details on that problem PC: see [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/165773)

Comment: @gnat is what I added enough?

Comment: per my reading of the FAQ it looks enough, although myself I typically also add my OS over that, in order to make sure that Stack Exchange developers can try to reproduce the issue in an environment as close to mine as possible

Comment: @gnat good point. Thanks!

Comment: _I am using chrome version 61.0.3141.8_ Latest Chrome official build is 59.x. 61 is Chrome canary which is nightly build and not officially supported by SE

Comment: @SagarV except for the fact that I don't use Canary...

Comment: I am on the latest version and mine is _59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit)_

Comment: Can you hit https://teststackoverflow.com/ and include the result?

Comment: @rene I'll post it the next time it happens. It's not a constant issue, but it sure does reproduce every so often (at least 10+ times a day)

Comment: @rene how should I include the results?

Comment: As a screenshot maybe?

Comment: @rene I have no idea what to make of the information. (So this is an opportunity to learn this thing :D)

Comment: Something on your side slows things down. First suspect is some security software messing with the browsers (e.g. it might inspect each request, scan it for viruses). Disable any anti virus or fancy security software you have and try. I'm pretty sure you'll have the pages load super fast as they do for all other people around the world.

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks. I have the windows defender but but I'll search for other suspects as well. Thanks again.

Comment: Nah, everyone got this, don't you have something else? Not only anti virus, maybe part of firewall software, or even network wide security system.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'll search. One moment

Comment: @ShadowWizard so, how will I know if it worked? I mean obviously if it stops getting stuck, but how will the teststackoverflow reflect this? (basically what's a normal graph on that site?)

Comment: You mean the pages are not always slow? In such case, not sure... don't stay unprotected for long time, but if it happens again, try to quickly disable the possible culprit program and reload quickly to see if it helped.

Comment: @ShadowWizard which anti virus would you recommend? Because it seems like this worked.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not using any antivirus for years now. All those I used were just terrible, starting with the non-free like Norton which was the worst, and even the free, "lightweight" ones, which were never light. They all caused the computer to be slow, never catched any single virus, and most also installed unwanted malware. (aka "toolbars")

Comment: Can you do a test over https as well? So visit [`https://teststackoverflow.com/`](https://teststackoverflow.com/) and it might be handy to include the guid that is in the full disclosure: `guid": "9f34c21a-fa4d-4e8b-bee0-94fe0dcb82ec",` for reference, this my result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDCkD.png on Win10/Chrome 59+

Comment: @rene I think the previous one is https... judging from the link... (the tab is still open)

Comment: If it is then that is strange because `Secure Connection Start` is missing from your screenshot

Comment: @rene the "full disclosure" section states `"secureConnectionStart": 0,` towards the end. I omitted it because that's a lot of lines. Should I add it? because I am not sure if the issue is resolved (as I said, it's non-consistent).

Comment: I'm only responding to what I see in your graph. This is what I get when I access that site over plain http: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcknA.png and that is similar to what your graph shows. That is why I asked to verify if you were indeed accessing over https. If you still insist that you are then this might be prove that something is tampering with the network on your end.

Comment: @rene well, this is interesting. when the problem is happening (usually a period of 1 or more minutes before it starts loading at normal speed) then I don't get the `Secure Connection Start`

Comment: definitely something in your network, networkdrivers/routing. Start in Safemode with Networking and see if you have the same issue. If yes, find another ISP preferable one that offers decent modems. If in safemode all works, disinfect your PC from viruses/rootkits, which isn't a bad idea at this stage anyway.

Comment: @rene ok. thanks for the help

Comment: @rene It's happening again, after a week or so without problems. I am starting to think it has something to do with reviewing on SO...